# Objective-C Multiarray to UIImage

Tags: opencv, uiimage, mat

The project is in Objective-C, combining OpenCV with MlModel

The mlmodel is working inside of OpenCV loop, due to use of OpenCV pre and postprocessing methods.
The input and output is an image.
The input for the model is Image (Color 224 x 224) the output is MultiArray (Double, 1 x 224 x 224).

[image]

The chain of conversion is (OpenCV format) Mat -> UIImage -> [MLMODEL] -> MultiArray -> UIImage -> Mat -> futher processing

I already checked the passing the data to the model.

The missing link is a conversion from MultiArray to UIImage.

How to convert (ML)MultiArray to UIImage? Or even better MLMultiArray directly to Mat in Objective-C. 
All the code I can find is in Swift, and it doesn't address this problem

Please help. Thanks in advance